# Where to put mods after installing mc-installer snap?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux, ubuntu

I installed Minecraft on Ubuntu 20.04 with `sudo snap install mc-installer`. I've also downloaded some mod .jar files, but there doesn't seem to be a "mods" folder within the installation – `find ~/snap/mc-installer -name mods` prints nothing. Where am I supposed to put the mods?

What I've tried based on suggestions from a couple websites:

- ~/snap/minecraft/common
- ~/snap/minecraft/common/mods
- ~/snap/mc-installer/current/.minecraft/mods

I have made sure the directory and .jar files are owned by the same user as the rest of the package (as you'd expect).

[Filed an issue with the package](https://github.com/kz6fittycent/mc-installer/issues/7).

Comment: If I understand [this moderator comment](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13559/where-can-i-ask-technical-troubleshooting-questions-about-modded-minecraft#comment46484_13560) correctly, this question does not fall under the "modded Minecraft" community reason for closing.

Answer (score 1):

First, just start unmodded Minecraft so that the `.minecraft` directory is instantiated, and locate it - it will probably appear in Snap's counterpart of `~/.minecraft`; it's the per-user directory of the game, as opposed to system-wide. Then run the mod loader installer that matches the mods of your choice (Fabric, Forge etc), giving it the path to .minecraft, e.g.

```
java -jar fabric-installer.jar client -dir "~/Games/.minecraft"
```

This will, among others, create the respective `.minecraft/mods` dir, where you should drop all the mods.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really want to install yet another thing just to install mods.

Answer (score 0):

Go get forge or other mod loaders, Minecraft doesn't automatically come with a mods folder. And one will be added after you install a mod loader to your Minecraft.